# Moody electrical outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle

The sink disposal came unscrewed, leaked, and shorted the unit. It died. I replace the disposal and plug it in. Nothing happens.

The breaker is not tripped. 
The new disposal turns on when an extension cord is used connected to a different outlet.
The outlet in question when tested indicated open ground.
We open it up and reconnect the ground.
Second outlet test shows open neutral.
We open it up, and the white wire is loose and falls off connection. We connect it firmly and test again. Hooray! Working outlet per the tester.
We plug the disposal in to the outlet and <<>>. The breaker again is not tripped. The outlet tester now has no lights on the outlet. Dead.
I plug the disposal with the cord into another outlet, it works.
It is clearly electrician time but this mystery is gnawing at my brain. 
Something about the disposal the outlet doesn't like. Or, would it do that with anything I plug in after it says it is working.
Probably needs a new outlet. Anyone have a technical insight into the reason this happened?

Comment: Maybe all three connections were loose? Did it get soaked when the sink leaked? That might have been enough to turn loose-but-functioning connections into loose-and-flaky. Rule of thumb, when you find one loose connection, check the others in the box.

Comment: You sure this isn't ran through a GFI?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback- I will reconnect all and see what happens. For the GFI, it's a metal box outlet, doesn't have red reset buttons like the ones in the bathroom. Maybe since it is under a SINK, it should? It looks like it wires straight through the wall into the garage where the breaker box is. The breaker is not tripped, it is a 15 double switch with the living room on the bottom and it is on the top. The contractors the builder hired for my house have been discovered to have been, shall we say, 'creative', on more than one occasion as we remodel.